# As a Sorcerer, how can I improve my reaction melee weapon attack?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, optimization, sorcerer

I'm hoping to play a melee Sorcerer with Mage Slayer and Sentinel feats, both of which provide good opportunities to use your reaction to make a Melee Weapon Attack. Currently, with 16 Dex, my best bet is a weapon with finesse, but I'm wondering whether there are other ways to boost my MWA attack bonus. E.g., at one point I considered Shillelagh, until I realised my Wisdom was less than my Dexterity, so, net decrease in to-hit.

I'm willing to dip up to 3 levels into other classes, hopefully without sacrificing more than 2 levels of caster, and ideally the solution won't require Concentration.

The emphasis is on boosting the Melee Weapon Attack provided by these two features: I'll be using Shocking Grasp (and other spells) for my Attack action.

My stat allocation at the moment is:

- 8 Str
- 16 Dex
- 12 Con
- 14 Wis
- 10 Int
- 16 Cha

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dipping 3 levels into Warlock, a Sorcerer can get Shillelagh via Pact of the Tome. Because it's acquired via a Warlock feature, Shillelagh will use Charisma instead of Wisdom for attack and damage.

With 20 Cha, your reaction (melee weapon) attack will be as good as any class except Rogue (unless I'm missing something).

Warlock will provide other sweet Cha-casting advantages, thereby having more overall synergy (though less damage output than Rogue in this specific department).

Comment: Actually, Shillelagh doesn't require concentration, so this is an even better idea.

Answer (score 5):

Truthfully, you're not going to find a weapon attack that scales well. *However*, that doesn't matter as much since you're looking for a weapon attack that is going to be used as your reaction and that actually means that scaling isn't nearly as important as I was originally thinking with this question.

This means that *basically any* melee attack that uses Dex is going to be Ok, and your best bet, if you think you can get advantage regularly is going to be the Rogue.

Three levels of Rogue will get you 2d6 Sneak attack dice with finesse weapons, which is about as good as you're possibly going to get. It also provides access to Cunning Action which is invaluable and can provide quite the advantage.

This build is already designed to play in melee, and it will be especially effective with those levels of rogue, especially if you can make sure that you are playing *with friends*.